# termio equivalent of stty command?

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I am writing a program to communicate over a serial port to a piece of hardware that utilizes XON. To make it work before my code executes I have to execute this on the command line (debian)

```
stty ixon -F /dev/ttyUSB0 sane raw pass8 -echo -hupcl clocal 115200
```

How can I do the equivalent in c++ so that I don't have to manually execute the command?

Here is what I have so far, which gets close. Writes seem to work fine. Reads are mostly fine but have a few garbled characters here and there plus data in seems to get mirrored over to the data out sometimes causing horrific loops with the hardware.

```
  //fd is a file descriptor pointing to /dev/ttyUSB0
  struct termios terminalAttributes;
  memset(&terminalAttributes, 0, sizeof(struct termios));

  if(tcgetattr(fd, &terminalAttributes) != 0) cout << "ERROR: Error getting terminalAttributes\n";

  terminalAttributes.c_cflag = B115200 | CS8 | CREAD; 
  terminalAttributes.c_iflag = IGNPAR |  ONLCR | IXON | IXOFF | IXANY;
  terminalAttributes.c_oflag = OPOST;
  terminalAttributes.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
  terminalAttributes.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;

  tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &terminalAttributes);
```

Comment: Note for comparison you can tcgetattr() after the manual stty

Comment: How do I examine the values? The bit wise flag stuff is mostly greek to me

Comment: You can also query with stty

Comment: Study [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237) and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html)  You mention using XON, which is aka soft flowcontrol, but are specifying `raw` or noncanonical mode implying binary data.  These are incompatible modes.  You should read the **stty** man page because your **stty** command has contradictory settings.